# Got #PYTHON! - unexpected failure in Python in Excel

Tags: python, excel, anaconda, office365

I have Excel Version 2309 (Build 16827.20000) through the Beta Channel of 365 Insider Program.
The Python (Preview) icons do appear in the Formulas ribbon.
I can also type Python code by `=PY` [tab]
However, none of the code works, including the built-in samples.
All I got is a `#PYTHON!` error. When I click show error message, it says "The Python interpreter returned the following error: Unexpected failure".

[image: The error message]

I have also tried each of the following codes like but all returns `#PYTHON!`

```
1+2
#Comment
xl("A1:E5")
```

In addition to Excel, do I need to install something else to get Python works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing you need to install, when its already showing a `PYTHON!` error hence its already in process, you will get sooner or later. Not 100% of Beta users are covered at once, new functionality is deployed by waves.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Mayukh. I did see `#BUSY!` appears briefly before `#PYTHON!` but nothing has changed after 15 minutes.
I have also tried `Reset`, `Reset Runtime` and `Ctrl-Alt-Shift-F9` but none helps.

Comment: Wait till `Tuesday` or late night updates today, may be it will start working, some of us here in `Beta` channel still we dont have access to it, at least you have it, wait for sometime.

Comment: Hmmm I wonder if we need a `python-vba` tag (yes, being facetious here).  If Python-in-Office takes off it will need better classification than `python` `excel` sprinkled around ad nauseam.

Comment: Same #PYTHON! error after upgrading from Build 16827.20000 to 16827.20004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem and finally solved. My 365 subscription is managed by my organization and I have two accounts: the first is my email with "company.com" domain, the second is my email with "company.onmicrosoft.com" domain. When I login with the first the PY function returns #PYTHON! error, while using the second with "onmicrosoft.com" domain it works. It seems a common issues for those having two accounts like me.

Comment: It works perfectly after switching from my free account to the paid O365 account. Thanks so much for your answer.